# Write a Unit test in Jest for a React form

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a form as follow:

```
import React from 'react/lib/ReactWithAddons';
import { server } from '../data/server';
export const Report = React.createClass({
    mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],

    sendReport(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = {
            ac: this.ab.checked,
            cp: this.cp.checked,
            nr: this.nr.checked,
            il: this.il.checked,
            message: this.message.value,
            name: this.name.value,
            affiliation: this.affiliation.value,
            email: this.email.value,
            address: this.address.value,
            city: this.city.value,
            country: this.country.value,
            zipcode: this.zipcode.value,
            phone: this.phone.value,
        };
        server.report(this.props.params.id, data,() => {  .....  });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <form  onSubmit={this.sendReport}>
                <div><input id='reason' ref={(ref) => this.ab = ref} name='reason'  type='radio' value='ab'  required /></div>
                <div><input id='reason' ref={(ref) => this.cp = ref} name='reason' type='radio' value='cp' /></div>
                <div><input id='reason' ref={(ref) => this.nr = ref} name='reason' type='radio' value='nr'  /></div>
                <div><input id='reason' ref={(ref) => this.il = ref} name='reason' type='radio' value='il'  /></div>
                <div><textarea ref={(ref) => this.message = ref}  name='message' className="form-control" type='textarea' rows="4" cols="50"  required/></div>
                <div><input id='name' ref={(ref) => this.name = ref} name='name' className="form-control" type='text'  required /></div>
                <div><input id='affiliation' ref={(ref) => this.affiliation = ref}  name='affiliation' className="form-control" type='text' required /></div>
                <div><input id='email' ref={(ref) => this.email = ref} name='email' className="form-control" type='email' required /></div>
                <div><input id='address' ref={(ref) => this.address = ref} name='address' className="form-control" type='text'  required /></div>
                <div><input id='city' ref={(ref) => this.city = ref} name='city' className="form-control" type='text'  required /></div>
                <div><select id='country' ref={(ref) => this.country = ref} name='country' className="form-control" defaultValue=""  required >
                    <option value="">Choose country</option>
                    <option value="Canada" >Canada</option> 
                    .... 
                    </select></div>
                <div><input id='zipcode' ref={(ref) => this.zipcode = ref} name='zipcode' className="form-control" type='text'  required /></div>
                <div><input id='phone' ref={(ref) => this.phone = ref} name="phone" type='text'  pattern="[0-9]*" className="form-control" title= "Numbers Only" required /></div>
                <div><button id='send' type="submit" >Send</button></div>
            </form>
        );
    }
});
```

Here is how I'm trying to write a unit test for it:

```
import { Report } from '../src/components/report';
import { server } from '../src/data/server';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react/lib/ReactWithAddons';
import { shallowToJson } from 'enzyme-to-json';
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';

describe('Report form', () => {
    const component = shallow(<Report params={{ id: '1033083fe' }} />);
    const sendReport = jest.fn();

    it('sends the form correctrly', ()=> {
        var data = {cp:true, message: 'testmessage', name:'testname', affiliation:'testaaa', email:'sss@test.com', address:'test address', city:'testcity', country:'testcountry', zipcode:'12345', phone: '0987654321'}
        const button = component.find('button');
        const cp = component.find('#cp');
        const message = component.find('#message');
        const name = component.find('#name');
        const affiliation = component.find('#affiliation');
        const email = component.find('#email');
        const address = component.find('#address');
        const city = component.find('#city');
        const country = component.find('#country');
        const zipcode = component.find('#zipcode');
        const phone = component.find('#phone');

        component.setState({ phone: '0987654321' });
        expect(component.find('#phone').length).toEqual(1);

        ## cp.simulate('change', { target: { value: true } });
        ## message.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'testmessage' } });
        name.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'testname' } });
        affiliation.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'testaaa' } });
        email.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'sss@test.com' } });
        address.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'test address' } });
        city.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'testcity' } });
        country.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'testcountry' } });
        zipcode.simulate('change', { target: { value: '12345' } });
        phone.simulate('change', { target: { value: '0987654321' } });
        button.simulate('click');

        expect(sendReport).toBeCalledWith(data);        
        expect(shallowToJson(component)).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

The goal is to check if the form sends the data correctly to the `sendreport()` method or not (after clicking the `send` button). All the fields are mandatory. The simulation of 'cp' and `message` fields returns this error:

```
Method “props” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.
```

So I had to comment them. But then I'll get this error:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledWith(expected)

Expected mock function to have been called with:
  [{cp:true, message: 'testmessage', name:'testname', affiliation:'testaaa', email:'sss@test.com', address:'test address', city:'testcity', country:'testcountry', zipcode:'12345', phone: '0987654321'}]
But it was not called.
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `server` is some external module that you import into your react component file like this:

```
import server from 'server'
```

Then you need to mock it in your test file like like this

```
import server from '../src/data/server'
jest.mock('../src/data/server', ()=> ({server: {report: jest.fn()}}))
```

In your test you can then expect thar `server.report` was called:

```
expect(server.report.mock).toBeCalledWith(data);
```

And to find only one element use `closest` instead of `find` as the later always returns an array of elements where you cant use `prop` on. If you use find you need to do it like this `component.find.first('button')`, this would be the same as `component.closest('button')`

Comment: It doesn't find `server`!! :-O  Returns this error: `Cannot find module 'server' from 'report-test.jsx'`

Comment: As I say, " I assume you import server". From your code its unclear where `server` comes from. Please update your question to show where server is coming from.

Comment: you're correct. I'm importing the `server` module from the correct path. Both the test doesn't understand it! :/ What `server` does is to get this data from form and trigger the related rest api thingi.

Comment: Please not that path must be relative to the test file.

Comment: As you use `import { server } ` the mock needs to changed to `jest.mock('../src/data/server', ()=> ({server: {report: jest.fn()}}))`

Comment: `jest.mock('../src/data/server', ()=> ({server: {report: jest.fn()}}));` works!  Now it's `expect(server.report).toBeCalledWith(data);` turn! It returns this error:
 `expect(jest.fn())[.not].toBeCalledWith()

    jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
    Received:
      function: [Function report]`

Comment: I've update my answer, needs to be `expect(server.report.mock).toBeCalledWith(data);`

Comment: hmmmm,getting this error: `expect(jest.fn())[.not].toBeCalledWith() 
    jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy. 
    Received: undefined`

Comment: Can you refer me to some good document to understand how mock is woking? Something other than [https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html]