# What is the difference between jest.mock(module) and jest.fn()

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, testunit, enzyme

I have tried couple different ways of defining the mock function and all of my tries failed. When I try to define it as follow:

```
jest.mock('../src/data/server', ()=> ({server: {report: jest.fn()}}));
expect(server.report.mock).toBeCalledWith(id, data, () => {...}, () => {...});
```

I get the this error:

```
expect(jest.fn())[.not].toBeCalledWith()
jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
Received: undefined
```

If I define the mock as :

```
var spy = jest.mock('../src/data/server', ()=> ({server: {report: jest.fn()}}));
expect(spy).toBeCalledWith(id, data, () => {...}, () => {...});
```

it returns the following error:

```
    expect(jest.fn())[.not].toBeCalledWith()
    jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
    Received:
      object: {"addMatchers": [Function anonymous], "autoMockOff": [Function anonymous], "autoMockOn": [Function anonymous], "clearAllMocks": [Function anonymous], "clearAllTimers": [Function anonymous], "deepUnmock": [Function anonymous], "disableAutomock": [Function anonymous], "doMock": [Function anonymous], "dontMock": [Function anonymous], "enableAutomock": [Function anonymous], "fn": [Function anonymous], "genMockFn": [Function bound getMockFunction], "genMockFromModule": [Function anonymous], "genMockFunction": [Function bound getMockFunction], "isMockFunction": [Function isMockFunction],
 "mock": [Function anonymous], "resetModuleRegistry": [Function anonymous], "resetModules": [Function anonymous], "runAllImmediates": [Function anonymous], "runAllTicks": [Function anonymous], "runAllTimers": [Function anonymous], "runOnlyPendingTimers": [Function anonymous], "runTimersToTime": [Function anonymous],"setMock": [Function anonymous], "unmock": [Function anonymous], "useFakeTimers": [Function anonymous], "useRealTimers": [Function anonymous]}
```

As my third try I defined the mock as:

```
const st = require.requireActual('../src/data/server', ()=> ({server: {report: jest.fn()}}));
st.report = jest.fn();
expect(st.report).toBeCalledWith(id, data,  () => {...}, () => {...});
```

And I get this error:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledWith(expected)
Expected mock function to have been called with:
  ["1033083fe", {"address": "test address", "affiliation": "testaaa", 
  "city": "testcity", "copyright": true, "country": "testcountry", "email": "sss@test.com", "message": "testmessage", 
  "name": "testname", "phone": "1234567890", "zipcode": "12345"}, [Function anonymous], [Function anonymous]]
But it was not called.
```

I wonder what is the problem and how these 3 ways of defining mock are different?

P.S. the code can be find here: [Write a Unit test in Jest for a React form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751053/write-a-unit-test-in-jest-for-a-react-form/40781209?noredirect=1#40751053)

Answer (score 18):

In the first example you say that when ever the module `'../src/data/server'` is imported in some other module it will be `{server: {report: jest.fn()}}`. In the next line you try to use `server`. The problem is that you never import the module that you mock. Maybe in the module that you test `server` is `{server: {report: jest.fn()}}`, but in you in test server is just `undefined` as you never import it. To fix this also have to import it.

```
import server from '../src/data/server'
jest.mock('../src/data/server', ()=> ({server: {report: jest.fn()}}));
expect(server.report.mock).toBeCalledWith(id, data, () => {...}, () => {...});
```

In the second example it seams like `jest.mock` just returns `jest`.

The last example fails cause you never call `st.report`.

Back to the main question. The difference between `jest.mock` and `jest.fn`

`jest.mock` replaces one module with either just `jest.fn`, when you call it with only the path parameter, or with the returning value of the function you can give it as the second parameter. So in your first example when ever in one of your files you wanna test or in the test itself, `'../src/data/server'` is imported it will be `{server: {report: jest.fn()}}`.

Which brings us the `jest.fn()`. This will return a spy. A spy is a function that can remember each call that was made on it, and with which parameters.

Lets say you have a module that you wanna test:

```
import server from './data/server'

server.report('test123')
```

To test that this call was made with the correct parameter you need to mock this dependency to `'./data/server'` with something you can control.

```
import server from '../src/data/server'
import fileToTest from '../src/fileToTest'
jest.mock('../src/data/server', ()=> ({server: {report: jest.fn()}}));
expect(server.report.mock).toBeCalledWith('test123');
```

What happens here is that before all the import stuff starts jest replaces  `'../src/data/server'` with your mock implementation, so when `fileToTest` is import the sever and call it, it actually call the spy function. Which you can then expect that it was called with the correct parameter.

Btw. what you try in your test, checking for function, will not work as the functions you pass when calling the spy and the function you pass into `toBeCalledWith` are not identical.

In this case I would check for each single parameter

```
expect(server.report.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe("1033083fe");
expect(server.report.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual({"address": "test address", "affiliation": "testaaa", 
  "city": "testcity", "copyright": true, "country": "testcountry", "email": "sss@test.com", "message": "testmessage", 
  "name": "testname", "phone": "1234567890", "zipcode": "12345"});
```